# How to model the croissant style ring?

Tags: screw-modifier

I would like to model the texture of this ring and have been stuck on this problem for a long time.

I would like to see the gap between each of the twist elements, and I would like to have each croissant twist to have a round / dome like look. Also, you can't tell but the back is hollow and has the shape of the twist.[image]

I have tried:

1. Screw modifier from a circle of 32 vertices. This does not work since it just looks like a rope with no gap in between twist elements.
2. starting out with UV sphere, applying simple deform to twist on z-axis, extruding faces or extruding edges inwards.
3. Starting out with torus and extruding the faces.

Nothing seems to look quite right.

[image]
[croissant ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nVf7.jpg)

Comment: I have a process that I think might work for this, and I’ve tested it out on low poly. I’ll try to get it to you as soon as possible. It involves bridging edge loops, and then moving some loops around with proportional editing turned on.

Comment: Here is a video tutorial I made: [Croissant Ring Blender Tutorial - Rumble](https://rumble.com/vsq5rg-croissant-ring-blender-tutorial-modeling-an-odd-piece-of-jewelry.html)
Hope it helps! If you need text based steps, I can do that.